# Build Application with asp net mvc3 and sql server enterprise edition server

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, asp.net-mvc-3-areas

I need to build an application that is using ASP NET MVC3 and try to connecting to SQL Server Enterprise Server. Could i make it? Because I don't have SQL Server Compact Edition installed and my boss want it to use SQL Server Enterprise Edition. Thx

Comment: Did you try to use `Database Explorer/Add Connection`?

Comment: I've tried to connect in my web.config  <connectionStrings>
    <!--<add name="HrDBContext"
         connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|Hr.sdf"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>-->
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="Data Source=localhost;User ID=sa;Password=karltigo;Initial Catalog=hr;Integrated Security=false;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: Your connection string point to a localhost. You want to connect to a remote server. `<add name="name" connectionString="Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=True;"
providerName=".NET Framework Data Provider for OLE DB"/>` Try to connect to the server using the wizard. (In my example I'm using windows authentication)

Comment: I use SQL Server Developer Edition. My Boss want me to connect to SQL Server not SQL Server Express. Could I use DAL?

Comment: In my last comment I put the example that I'm using to connect my web application to my production's server (SQL Server Enterprise edition). What did you do so far?  Did you migrate you database to production's server?

Comment: Thx all. I've succeded connecting to sql server enterprise / developer edition. I made the folder APPCODE not APP_CODE cause it's not working. APP_CODE run or is executed after the MVC. Just the Namespace playing. Enjoy your coding.